# What happens if we split a sphere

Tags: electrostatics

I came up with the following problem and I'm trying to understand this concept.

Consider a conducting sphere with radius R and charge Q uniformly distributed [since it's a conductor, it is of course distributed on the surface]. If we calculate the electrostatic energy of the sphere we come with $$ \frac{Q^2}{2R4\pi\epsilon_o}  $$
[I had no trouble coming up with this expression, using the Maxwell integral for energy]. Now, at some moment the sphere splits into two equal spheres, that get very far away from each other. This will imply a decrease on the electrostatic energy.

My question is why a decrease? Why doesn't energy just equally divides between the 2 spheres. Will not charge redistribute itself equally between the 2 spheres. Can we prove that energy was dissipated?

Answer (score 2):

The two parts repel each other: that force will do work as they move apart.  It could move energy out of the electrical form and into kinetic energy as they fly apart; or into work on whatever is holding as they push apart; etc. But a repelling force, dotted into moving apart, is work that removes energy.